# Calculate a triple integral - variable changed into spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem is to calculate
$$\iiint_D x^2\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where $D$ is determined by $x^2+2y^2+z^2\le2$.

- [solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndc0jx4eslid398/Screenshot%202014-04-18%2011.43.39.png)
- my attempt:

[image]

why can I not do it like that? I change variables, calculate the jacobian, and follow the usual steps.

Comment: You can, there is nothing wrong with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your problem is:

$$\iiint_{D}x^{2}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z,$$

Where $D$ is the region described by: $x^{2}+2y^{2}+z^{2}\leq 2$. Which is a triple integral, rather than the double integral that you describe, however, the process is much the same. We first describe our transformation from Cartesian co-ordinates into the new co-ordinate system:

$$\begin{align}x&=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi) \\ y&=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) \\ z&=r\cos(\theta)\end{align}$$

We then compute our Jacobian:

$$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\varphi)}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \varphi} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \varphi}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi) & r\cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi) & -r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) & \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi) & \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi) \\ \cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) & 0\end{vmatrix}$$

Evaluating this determinant gives us:

$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\varphi)}\right|=\frac{r^{2}\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

And therefore:

$$\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z=\frac{r^{2}\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{2}}\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta\:\mathrm{d}\varphi$$

We then look at our constaints and conclude that:

$$r\in[0,\sqrt{2}],\,\theta\in[0,\pi],\,\varphi\in[0,2\pi]$$

We therefore have:

$$\iiint_{D}x^{2}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}z=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\varphi)\right)\left(\frac{r^{2}\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta\:\mathrm{d}\varphi$$

We can simplify this to give:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}r^{4}\sin^{3}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\varphi)\:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta\:\mathrm{d}\varphi=\frac{16\pi}{15}$$

Comment: He never mentioned double integrals.

Comment: @Fantini Sorry, I started writing this answer before it was edited by other people but then got distracted and only just finished it.

Comment: I have slacked off with my trig id, which ones are used here? cos^2 would be by double angle?  sin^3 with sin^2=(1-cos^2) and then chain rule in reverse?

Comment: I have simply used $\sin^{2}(\theta)+\cos^{2}(\theta)\equiv 1$, $\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$ here in evaluating the Jacobian. Where are you stuck at the moment?

Comment: No, I mean in the end. How you arrive at $16 \pi /15$

Comment: There are several ways to do it, a very general method is [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution), alternatively you can use the double angle identities: $$\sin^{2}(\theta)\equiv\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2},\quad \cos^{2}(\theta)\equiv\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}$$